# When to use new for an object and when to use pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

For example, I have a vector which is declared this way:

```
    vector<Shapes> *ShapeVector;
```

If I want to have a shape object, and to be able to access different shapes that're of different sizes, would declaring 'new' or not be needed? What about pointers then?

To me, pointers point to different addresses to access. So, would I need pointers too?

So far, I did the following code to create my object, and to store arrays in it. After that, I would plan to store the object into the vector itself.

```
    int tempx[100],tempy[100];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4;i ++)
  {
    cout << "Enter x-coordinate of pt " << i << ":" << endl;
    cin >> tempx[i];
    cout << "Enter y-coordinate of pt " << i << ":" << endl;
    cin >> tempy[i];
Square mysquare = new Square(tempx,tempy);
```

Not sure if it's correct though, unsure on when to use 'new' and when to use pointers.

Comment: It might be worth to see these [slides](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1)

Comment: The `*` should be inside the `<>` (after the `Shapes`). Also, asking when to use `new` and when to use pointers is like asking if an apple is greener or sweeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simply `std::vector<Shapes> my_vector`, without pointers. The vector object will be allocated on the stack, its content on the heap. You will have the advantage that the Shape objects will be placed contiguously in memory.